# Expressing "at most" in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I need to translate to predicate logic: "Every natural number is the sum of at most four squared natural numbers". The word that causes problems for me is the word "at most".

Here is what I have right: $ ∀ n {\in}\mathbb N \; ∃ a,b,c,d {\in} \mathbb N\quad a^2 +b^2+c^2+d^2 = n^2$. How do I integrate the restriction "at most four numbers"?

Comment: Easy in this case, as you can just allow your variables to be $0$.

Comment: "At most $n$" needs $n$ existential quantifiers with the additional clause that every $n+1$ variables must be equal to one of the previous.

Comment: it means every number is the sum of one, two, three, or four squares. You don't have to deal with five!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA 1. Careful though: your specification tries to weed out additional distinct variables, but is overaggressive when the first n variables aren't even distinct from one another. 2. The OP's statement doesn't admit <310; 1,2,4,17,17>, but your specification appears to admit it.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say "at most four" means "one or two or three or four".  Then you can translate the statement as

\begin{align*}
\forall n\in \mathbb{N},(&(\exists a\in\mathbb{N}, n = a^2) \\
& \vee(\exists a,b\in\mathbb{N}, n = a^2+b^2) \\
& \vee(\exists a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}, n = a^2+b^2+c^2) \\
& \vee(\exists a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}, n = a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2))
\end{align*}

First-order predicate logic doesn't have a way to quantify over the number of quantifiers, so, without pulling tricks (like using the fact that $0^2$ is an additive unit) you need to translate each possibility independently and form their disjunction.

Comment: how would you scale this to at most n case?

Comment: @senseiwu Do you mean for specific n, or for a variable n? The second case needs set theory, I'm fairly sure, but it's not so hard.  For the first, you just add as many "there exists" as you need.

Answer (score 1):

> "Every natural number is the sum of at most four squared natural numbers".

1. Disambiguate:

   “Every natural number is expressible as a sum of squared natural numbers, requiring at most four.”
2. Rephrase equivalently for easier translation:

   “Every natural number is expressible as the sum of exactly four squared integers.”
3. Translate:

   $$\forall n{\in}\mathbb N\:\: \exists a,b,c,d{\in}\mathbb Z\quad
      n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2.$$

   (This is actually Lagrange's Four-Square Theorem.)

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{Z}$ make it easier to translate? Does your $\mathbb{N}$ not include $0$?